# How to fix the problem of react app not loading in Safari?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, fetch

I built an application by using create-react-app, react-redux, react-router-dom, and material UI. The app uses Fetch API for http requests.
It's working in Chrome, but in Safari I get the error below.

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext

app link: https://app.evewellness.ir/

Comment: Which version of Safari, which platform, and what's your console errors if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a message in Safari console about AudioContext:
"ReferenceError: Can't find variable: AudioContext".

Check this I guess it will help = [AudioContext on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29373563/audiocontext-on-safari) .